# Encounter Error regarding javascript and JSON

Tags: javascript, json

i am learning JSON. i just write a simple code which is not working and also not giving any error when clicking on button. so please help me to catch the error. here is my html.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function GetJSON() 
        {
            alert("pp");

            var moviereviewtext = "{"title": "Friday the 13th", "year": 1980, "reviews": 
            [{"reviewer": "Pam", "stars": 3, "text": "Pretty good, but could have used more Jason"}, 
            {"reviewer": "Alice", "stars": 4, "text": "The end was good, but a little unsettling"}]}";
            var jsonobj = eval("(" + moviereviewtext + ")");

            var reviewername = jsonobj.reviews[0].reviewer;
            var numberstars = jsonobj.reviews[0].stars;
            var reviewerthoughts = jsonobj.reviews[0].text;

            alert(reviewername);
            alert(numberstars);
            alert(reviewerthoughts);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="GetJSON();return false;" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is browser dependent but with a few small changes:

```
// Use single quote to surround and line continuations to support new lines.
var movieReviewText = 
    '{"title": "Friday the 13th", "year": 1980, "reviews":\
    [{"reviewer": "Pam", "stars": 3, "text": "Pretty good, but could have used more Jason"},\ 
    {"reviewer": "Alice", "stars": 4, "text": "The end was good, but a little unsettling"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(movieReviewText); // This should be available IE8+, FF3+
```

Also, take note that a function that starts with a capital letter is by convention considered a constructor. The name of your function also could be made better as the function does not actually get JSON. Maybe something like this?

```
function parseMovieReview() {


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the ASP code.
Try leaving ASP aside. Following code works for me:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function GetJSON() 
        {
            alert("pp");

            var moviereviewtext = '{"title": "Friday the 13th", "year": 1980, "reviews":\
            [{"reviewer": "Pam", "stars": 3, "text": "Pretty good, but could have used more Jason"},\
            {"reviewer": "Alice", "stars": 4, "text": "The end was good, but a little unsettling"}]}';
            var jsonobj = eval("(" + moviereviewtext + ")");

            var reviewername = jsonobj.reviews[0].reviewer;
            var numberstars = jsonobj.reviews[0].stars;
            var reviewerthoughts = jsonobj.reviews[0].text;

            alert(reviewername);
            alert(numberstars);
            alert(reviewerthoughts);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <form id="form1">
        <Button ID="Button1" Text="Button" OnClick="GetJSON();return false;" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```